# python tkinter listbox - insert error

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I cannot 'insert' a string into my tkinter listbox. My code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilenames

def ImportFiles():
    Tk().withdraw()
    filenames = askopenfilenames()
    for f in filenames:
        listbox1.insert(END, f)
    return

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x800")

listbox1 = Listbox(root).grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=20, pady=20)
button1 = Button(root, text='Import', command=ImportFiles).grid(row=2, sticky=W, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run this snippet of code the GUI pops up fine. I press the button and and open file dialog comes up, as expected. Then when I select some files and press 'Ok' the code bombs. I get the following error:

File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in **call**

return self.func(*args)

File ".../pyGUI_01.py", line 10, in ImportFiles

listbox1.insert(END, f)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

I don't understand. I set the object 'listbox1' to the TK Listbox. There is no indication in my IDE that the command 'insert' is not valid (PyCharm). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, there are many questions that would solve your problem if you had researched them. Show us what you've done to solve the problem yourself. Please read [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section carefully.

Comment: Secondly, `filenames = askopenfilenames()`: this single line of code does not get any value from a file you select.

Comment: @Parviz. filenames = askopenfilenames() DOES get the file names. I used the 'print' statement to see them. It generates a Tuple of Strings. Have you tried using this before yourself?

Comment: I thought you want to get "what's inside" the files you select.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley. It is not abundantly clear that this is a duplicate to me. I looked at other Q&A and didn't find anything to indicate why my code wasn't working. It was even less clear that "grid" was the issue. I wouldn't have put that together from the duplicate post. Either way I got what I needed from Fhaab.

Comment: The first step should always be to do a google or stackoverflow search for the error. Searching for "NoneType object has no attribute" yields *lots* of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your variable "listbox1" to the result of grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=20, pady=20).

Try two lines:

```
listbox1 = Listbox(root)
listbox1.grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=20, pady=20)
```

Now listbox1 is actually set to an instance of Listbox, and not the result of "grid()."

Comment: That did it. Works perfectly. I didn't realize I couldn't use "grid" on the same line.

Answer (score -1):

Fhaab is correct, but why are you creating a new Tk instance and then destroying it with Tk().withdraw()?

Comment: this does not answer the question.

Comment: I'm trying to learn about tkinter so I am doing a lot of things to see what happens.